# Layout a UIStackView inside UICollectionViewCell

Tags: autolayout, ios-autolayout

I have a UICollectionViewCell that displays three information: an image, the title to the image, and some descriptions of that image.

But the layout has been troublesome to me.

[image: No constraints.]

I try to add constraints to the UIStackView so that all information can display with nicely layout. But it after adding constraints, the layout guide lines become red.

[image: Four constraints.]

---

Meanwhile, I tried to layout all the stuff without using stack view to enclosing the 3 components. But that was also messy. I tried to programmatically calculate calculate cell size in `collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt)`. But I was stuck at the cell height. Because the `Title` and `Detail` labels can have dynamic height due to the difference of text in each picture.

**Am I working toward the right direction? At this moment, I just could not see how things would work out...**

Comment: Is your layout designed to show a "single-column" collection view? Or multiple "columns" in a flow-layout?

Comment: It is designed to be something like the new Today on the App Store. It shows multiple columns on iPad and one column on iPhone portrait.

Comment: I know there is a reference/sample project on GitHub mocking the Today tab. But that project is using constant height, not dynamic and adapting to the content it displayed.